# Creating in-order-keys with `etcdctl`

Tags: etcd

I'm planning to use etcd as a key-value store.

I found that etcd has a API that I can create in-order keys.

https://coreos.com/etcd/docs/0.4.7/etcd-api/#atomically-creating-in-order-keys

Python etcd client support this API.

https://python-etcd.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#set-a-key

However, I'm not sure how to do it with `etcdctl` command.
`etcdctl set` seems not to have append option.

Is there any way to crate create-in-order-keys with `etcdctl`?

Answer (score 0):

… apparently not.

Use curl, or a small Python program. Or post a bug report and wait. ;-)